# How to load an image and text beside that image using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm able to load all the 5 images in a div.Now I'm trying to add text beside each image respectively.Suppose if the image is crop.I'm trying to add crop text beside that image using angularjs.How can I achieve this.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My html code:

```
<div style="margin-top: 4px;">
                    <img width=30 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;"
                        ng-repeat="generalimage in generalimages track by $index"
                        ng-src="{{generalimage}}"> </img>
                </div>
```

My js code:

```
$scope.generalimages = [];
    $scope.generalimages.push('images/Undo.png');
    $scope.generalimages.push('images/Resize.png');
    $scope.generalimages.push('images/Rotate.png');
    $scope.generalimages.push('images/Resolution.png');
    $scope.generalimages.push('images/Crop.png');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know what you mean by beside image, It could be tooltip text or just simple text after image. You could achieve this by doing :

JS

```
$scope.generalimages = [{
  "image":"images/Undo.png",
  "text" : "Undo"},
 {
  "image":"images/Resize.png",
  "text" : "Resize"},
{
  "image":"images/Rotate.png",
  "text" : "Rotate"},
{
  "image":"images/Resolution.png",
  "text" : "Resolution"},
{
  "image":"images/Crop.png",
  "text" : "Crop"},
  ];
```

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li  ng-repeat="item in generalimages track by $index">
      <img ng-src="{{item.image}}"></img>
      <span>{{item.text}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm able to get the list of images in a vertical manner.But I want to load this list in the horizontal manner.How can I do this ?

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya if you keep all images in the single DIV its not ideal, Plus  you wont have full control to style it independently, my suggestion would be use it in UL -> LI and style it accordingly

Comment: Actually,I have a small div.In that I need to fit all these images in a horizontal manner along with the text beside to that images.How can I do this using UL->LI

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya set width to ul  and make LI float left or display: inline-block this will do the job. if you have plunker i will help you

Comment: Ya,Now it's working fine for me.Thanks a lot for ur help

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to append the text besides your image-

```
<div>
    <img src=""/>
    <span display: block>Text below the image</span>
</div>
```